# What is the meaning of expression $(X_i−\bar{X})′$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I came across an expression ($X_i−\bar{X}$)′ while going through covariance matrix calculation.

I know $X_i$ is a random variable and $\bar{X}$  is the mean of all variables, but I cant figure out the meaning of ′. Also if I have $X_i$ as 4.0 and $\bar{X}$ as 4.10 what is the result of ($X_i−\bar{X}$)′ expression?

Comment: That is transposing. $X_i$ can be vectors.

Comment: @gunes Can you please help me understand how they came up with COV(X) here -- https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section5/pmc541.htm?

Comment: covariance formula is $E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])']$. Unbiased estimation of this is achieved by calculating the sum and dividing by $\frac{1}{n-1}$

Comment: @gunes Ya but how are they calculating (X−E[X]) ? I now understand that (Y−E[Y])′ is the transpose of (Y−E[Y]). How are they calculating X−E[X] when X is a 5x3 and E[X] is a 1x3 matrix ? Sorry if I am being too dumb.

Comment: If X is 5x3, then you have 5 samples. Each of them is 1x3. You'll calculate $X_i-E[X]$ and sum.

Comment: @gunes: you might want to consider writing up your comments as an answer so it can be upvoted. :)